# Заполнение n-нного количества файлов по шаблону Java

Tags: java, файлы, copy

Задача следующая...Есть у меня папка с файлами и отдельно шаблон, мне надо циклом пройтись по каждому файлу и заполнить его по шаблону.
Проблема в том что я не до конца понимаю как заставить програмку это сделать.

Вот то что я написал

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DocxPhiller {


    public static void Fill(){
int fileCount = new File("/Users/admin/Desktop/AutoLab").listFiles().length;

try {
    FileReader filePatt = new FileReader("pattern.txt");
    int c = filePatt.read();
    for (int i = 0; i<= fileCount; i++){
          


        }
}catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}finally {

}
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы сначала напишите для одного файла, а потом заключите написанное в цикл.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую